# ProxyPass with a port in Apache Virtualhost does not work

Tags: apache, wso2, virtualhost, mod-proxy, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager. I have fronted API Manager(tomcat) with an Apache HTTP Server.

For the URL `api.abc.xyz.lk` a public IP has been assigned. For that public IP a local IP which is `192.168.6.162` has been assigned. I have added a virtual-host to redirect all the `http://api.abc.xyz.lk` to `http://192.168.6.162:9763/store`.

What I'm trying to do here is redirect all the `http://api.abc.xyz.lk` requests to `http://192.168.6.162:9763/store`.

Below is the virtual-host block I use.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
        ServerName api.abc.xyz.lk
        ServerAlias api.abc.xyz.lk
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off

        ProxyPass /  http://192.168.6.162:9763/store
        ProxyPassReverse /  http://192.168.6.162:9763/store

</Virtualhost>
```

The problem is

the URL that works is as below

http://api.abc.xyz.lk:9763/store

But actually what I want is

http://api.abc.xyz.lk

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

you need to modify this proxy pass

```
 ProxyPass /store  http://192.168.6.162:9763/store
 ProxyPassReverse /store  http://192.168.6.162:9763/store
```

this will do the trick..

make sure to enable the proxy ports in server, you can configure proxy ports by editing "catalina-server.xml" in $UES_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml

Comment: If I so that http://api.abc.xyz.lk/store will be redirected to http://192.168.6.162:9763/store. But what I want is http://api.abc.xyz.lk to http://192.168.6.162:9763/store